# Stranga ordo de "ago" + "priskribo"

Tags: correlatives, word-order, subordinate-clauses

Jen du frazoj sufiĉe ordinaraj.

> La tasko estas facile farebla.
> Estas facile fari la taskon.

Tiuj du havas signifon efektive saman, kaj ili estas same oftaj (miasperte, laŭ miaj oreloj). Kiel strange estus reordigi la duan ke la objekto staru ĉe la komenco?

> La taskon estas facile fari.

Unuavide, tiu eble ŝajnus kvazaŭ erara, sed la celon klarigus la frazo originala. Nun, kial uzus/volus mi tian ordon? Pro tio ke ĉe la objekto povus stari anstataŭe k-korelativo.

> Bonvole trovu por la komencanto taskon, **kiun** estus facile fari.

Mi ne certas ĉu tia uzado estus ĝusta. Ĝi certe ŝajnus stranga al miaj okuloj. Estus pli kutime diri anstataŭe "kiu estus facile farebla", sed estus iom interese uzi la ordon strangan. Laŭ mi estas ebleto ke ĝi estus ĝusta, pro tio ke eblas kurtigi subfrazon, kiel la jena.

> Mi ne scias, **kion** fari.

Sed mi ne certas ĉu estus laŭregule apliki tiun permeson en tiu okazo. Ĉiuokaze, mi ne zorgas pri kutimeco/komprenebleco. Ĉio ĉitiea estas por vortludo.

#### Klarigo

Mi celas uzi la formon "X-on estas Y-e Z-i" **nur kiel reordigon** de "estas Y-e Z-i X-on". Alivorte, se paroli pri la strukturo "X estas Y", en tiu okazo estas nur la Y.

Answer (score 2):

Ni komencu per **transitiva** frazo, alivorte per frazo kun rekta objekto.

> Mi faras la taskon.

La gramatiko de Esperanto permesas, ke oni povas reordigi la frazon ekzemple al

> La taskon mi faras.

Tio eblas, ĉar la subjekto kaj la objekto havas malsimilajn montrilojn por sia rolo (la subjekto estas en la nominativo sen aparta montrilo; la objekto en la akuzativo kun la n-finaĵo).

Ekzistas ankaŭ alispecaj verboj ol transitivaj. Ekzistas **netransitivaj** verboj ("Mi dormas"), kun kiuj sufiĉas unu substantivo, la subjekto, aŭ kiuj estas sensubjektaj ("Neĝas"). La tria speco de verboj estas **kopuloj**, kiuj konektas du esprimojn (de latino "copula", bindo, bindaĵo). Kvankam entute ne ekzistas multaj kopulaj verboj, oni uzas la ekzistantajn tre multe, speciale du, "esti" kaj "fariĝi". Ĉar la kopuloj konektas la du partojn laŭ ago de la verbo, la ordo gravas.

Ekzemple

> Leono estas besto ≠ Besto estas leono.

(Rimarku, ke mi forlasis la artikolon por pli klare ilustri la ideon.)

Notu, ke mi skribis, ke kopula konektas du esprimojn. Tiuj du esprimoj povas havi diversajn formojn. En via unua ekzemplo "La tasko estas facile farebla" la unua parto, "la tasko", estas substantivo, sed la dua estas adjektivo, kiu havas adverban komplementon. Kiam temas pri la dua ekzemplo "Estas facile fari la taskon", oni povas pensi, ke la kopula konektas la adverbon "facile" al la infinitiva esprimo "fari la taskon". Ĉar adverbo ne povas esti subjekto en Esperanto, oni diras, ke la frazo estas sensubjekta, kaj oni kutime skribas tiajn frazojn tiel, ke la verbo komenciĝas la frazon.

Kompreneble oni povas konekti substantivon al infinitivo

> La tasko estas facile fari.

aŭ infinitivan esprimon al adverbo

> Fari la taskon estas facile.

Se tia infinitivo havas ian komplementon (aŭ adverban, objektan aŭ alian), tiu tutaĵo rolas kiel unu frazparto kaj ne povas esti apartigita de alia grava frazparto, ekzemple subjekto aŭ ĉefverbo.

Comment: Kvankam tiu ĉi respondo aldonas pli da bonaj rimedoj por estigi la esprimon celitan (danko estu al vi pro tio), kaj klarigas la veran strukturon de ĉiu frazo (plian dankon), mia ĉefa demando ankoraŭ estas. Ĉu la reordigo menciita (t.e. tiu kun objekto) estas gramatike [mal]ĝusta? Tiu temo min tiom interesas, ĉar ĝi miarigarde estas pri nur simpla reordigo, en kiu la rolo de ĉiu vorto en la originala restus sama (miakonjekte). La "estas", laŭ vi, ankoraŭ konektus la adverbon al la esprimo "fari la taskon". La nura malsamo laŭ mi estas ke la objekto de "fari" starus aliloke.

Comment: Laŭ mia interpreto de ĉi tiu respondo, jes, tiu reordigo estas malĝusta pro tio ke la vortordo ĉe la verbo “esti” ne estas tute libera. Tamen mi ne certas ĉu “Fari la taskon estas facile” kaj “Estas facile fari la taskon” havas malsamajn gramatikajn konstruojn aŭ temas pri la sama afero en alia ordo.

Comment: Dankon pro reagoj. Mi ŝanĝis terminon kaj aldonis linion pri nedivideblo laŭ la ideo de @marcus.

Comment: Ŝajnas ke ano (nu, estro) de /r/Esperanto trovis por mi multon da trafoj je tio, kion mi serĉas. https://tekstaro.com/?s=62f3fa35b8981

Comment: @MonatheMonad Ho ve, kiel kompleksa serĉo, sed kiel bonaj rezultoj! Do, tiu fraz-konstruo estas ebla kaj ĉiuj respondoj ĝis nun estas malĝustaj... Mi pensas ke vi povas aldoni vian propran respondon al via demando. Ne lasu tiun bonan trovaĵon de Tekstaro nur en malgranda komento ĉi tie.

Comment: Mi kreis [babilejon](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138438/stranga-ordo-de-ago-priskribo) por ĉi tiu demando.

Answer (score 2):

- Bonvole trovu por la komencanto taskon, kiun fari estus facile.
- Bonvole trovu por la komencanto taskon, kiu estus facile farebla.
- Bonvole trovu por la komencanto taskon, kies farado (plenumo) estus facila.

Metante la verbon ĉe la akuzativo (unua frazo) oni gajnas kompreneblon, precipe de la uzo kiel objekto. Kaj kiu krome pli sekvas la logikon de la dua kaj tria frazoj.

Por ne tro streĉi la cerbon aliaj fluaj frazoj estas penseblaj - evitantaj la problemon:

- Bonvolu trovi facile fareblan taskon por la komencanto.
- Bonvolu trovi plenumeblan taskon por la komencanto.

Answer (score 2):

Surprize, ŝajnas ke tia reordigo ja eblas. Bona ano kaj amiko de /r/Esperanto (fakte estro) trovis por mi [multe da trafoj de tia kontruo](https://tekstaro.com/?s=62f3fa35b8981). Kvankam mi ne ankoraŭ scias, kio estas la regulo mem kiu estras tiun aferon, estas sufiĉe laŭ mi, ke estas tiom da trafoj, por konkludi ke tia reordigo estas ĝusta. Sed, konsiderante ke ĉiuj respondoj ĝis nun aŭ (0) sugestas ke ĝi estas malĝusta aŭ (1) proponas rimedon alternativan por esprimi la signifon celitan (eble pro malĝusteco perceptita), mi opinias ke tia konstruo eble estigus por iuj iom da konfuzo en normala interparolado. Do, ĝi eble estas ne tiom uzinda, eble krom por ion ial emfazi per tia ordo.

Danko estu al Ajno pro la trovo per serĉilo tiel absurda.

Answer (score 1):

Kial ne diri : "Bonvolu trovi, por la komencanto, facil-faran taskon"?

Comment: Ĉar tiam la dubo plu restos kaj oni neniam lernos.

Answer (score -1):

```
La taskon estas facile fari.
```

Tiu frazo estas unuavide malĝusta ĉar la ĉefa verbo estas `esti`, ne `fari`.

*Io estas io* (sen `-n` ambaŭflanke de `esti`).

Trovi kelkajn similaĵojn en Tekstaro ne igas tion ĝusta. Ekzemple, Zamenhof skribis jenon, kio pravigus la ordon de via frazo:

```
Funebron estas tre facile ludi.
```

sed ankaŭ:

```
Ĉu [...]iris ĉiuj la dioj de l’ malnova tempo?
```

*ĉiuj la dioj* estas malĝusta laŭ [la malpermesoj de *la*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/la/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-bgj) en PMEG.

Do, ĉar oni povus kompreni `La taskon estas facile fari`, kaj pro tio ke aperas kelkaj trafoj en Tekstaro (ĉefe dum la unuaj jaroj de la lingvo) oni povus konsideri tiun ordon ebla (same ebla kiel *ĉiuj la*, ni diru) sed samtempe evitenda.

Comment: Vortordo en Esperanto estas sufiĉe fleksebla, kvankam ne tute tia. Se "estas facile fari la taskon" estas ĝusta, kial estus ke la reordigita (t.e. la rolo de ĉiu vorto restus sama) ne estas ĝusta? Unu el la nuraj logikaj respondoj kiujn povas mi elpensi estas ke tia reordigo ne eblas. Ĉu tiu estas vera?

Comment: Mi ne scius kiel plu klarigi ... Demandu al la verbo en via frazo, *kio estas kio*? Tion vi devus povi respondi per du nominativecaj elementoj. Vi ne povas, do la frazo ne ĝustas.

Comment: Jes, mi ja povas respondi. Vi respondas kvazaŭ estas en la frazo kaj subjekto kaj ĝia komplemento (t.e. kvazaŭ, en la formo "X estas Y", estas kaj X kaj Y). En la senco de la vera strukturo, en mia frazo estas nur la Y (la verbo "fari"). La X tute ne estas, ĉar la "la taskon" ne estas X. Se la frazo ĉiuokaze estas malĝusta, ne senchavas laŭ mi ke ĝi estus malĝusta pro la "io estas io" problemo.